# Autocompletado a través de un select foreignk key (Django)

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

Tengo una consulta y es que tengo 2 modelos uno llamado 
**DetalleVenta** que hace referencia al segundo modelo **Producto**

```
class DetalleVenta(models.Model):
   producto = models.ForeignKey(Producto,on_delete=models.CASCADE,verbose_name='Producto')
   cantidad = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Cantidad')
   preciounit = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=7, verbose_name='Precio unitario')
   subtotal = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=7, verbose_name='Subtotal')
   venta = models.ForeignKey(Venta,on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='detalleventa', verbose_name='Venta')

def __str__(self):
    return '{} - {}'.format(self.venta,self.producto)

class Producto(models.Model):
   nombre = models.CharField(max_length=30,unique=True,verbose_name='Nombre de Producto:')
   precio = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=7, verbose_name='Precio de Producto:')
   categoria = models.ForeignKey(Categoria,on_delete=models.CASCADE,verbose_name='Categoría:')

def __str__(self):
    return self.nombre
```

Y en mi forms.py del Detalle tengo :

```
class DetalleForm(forms.ModelForm):
  class Meta:
    model = DetalleVenta
    fields = [
        'producto',
        'cantidad',
        'preciounit',
        'subtotal',
    ]
    labels = {
        'producto':'Producto',
        'cantidad':'Cantidad',
        'preciounit':'Prec.Unit.',
        'subtotal':'Subtotal',
    }
    widgets = {
        'producto':forms.Select(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
        'cantidad':forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class':'form-control cantidad'}),
        'preciounit':forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
        'subtotal':forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class':'form-control subtotal', 'readonly':True}),
    }
  DetalleFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Venta, DetalleVenta,
                                   form=DetalleForm, extra=1)
```

Como pueden observar en el formulario de detalle tengo un campo **preciounit** que hace referencia al precio del producto el cual esta en el modelo **producto** y mi pregunta es: hay alguna manera de que en mi template del detalle al seleccionar por ejemplo un producto X **(foreing key que hace referencia al producto)** me autocomplete en el input de **preciounit** con su respectivo precio?

Este es mi template:

```
{% extends 'base/base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block titulo%} Registrar venta {%endblock%}
{% block contenido %}
<div class="col-md-12">
<form method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    <div class="col-md-4 form-group">
    <label class="font-weight-bold" for="{{form.cliente.name}}">{{form.cliente.label}}</label>
    {{form.cliente}}
    </div>
    <h4 class="text-left">Detalle de venta: </h4>
    <div class="table-responsive-sm">
        <table class="table" id="tablaDetalle">
            {{ detalleformset.management_form }}
            <thead class="thead-dark">
                <th>Producto</th>
                <th width="100px">Cantidad</th>
                <th width="115px">Prec.Unit.</th>
                <th width="115px">Subtotal</th>
                <th>Acción</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            {% for form in detalleformset.forms %}
                <tr class="formset_row">
                    {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
                        <td>
                            {# Include the hidden fields in the form #}
                            {% if forloop.first %}
                                {% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
                                    {{ hidden }}
                                {% endfor %}
                            {% endif %}
                            {{ field.errors.as_ul }}
                            {{ field }}
                        </td>
                    {% endfor %}
                </tr>
            {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
        </table>
        </div>
        <div class="row justify-content-md-end">
        <div class="col-md-2">
        <label class="font-weight-bold" for="{{form.total.name}}">{{form.total.label}}</label>
        {{form.total}}
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
        <label class="font-weight-bold" for="{{form.descripcion.name}}">{{form.descripcion.label}}</label>
        {{form.descripcion}}
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 offset-md-4">
          <button class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-primary" type="submit"><span><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>
          </span>Registrar venta</button>
        </div>
    </form>
    </div>
   {% endblock %}
   {% block javascript %}
   <script src="{% static 'js/jquery.formset.js' %}"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
    $('.formset_row').formset({
        addText: 'Agregar Producto',
        deleteText: 'remover',
        prefix: 'detalleventa'
    });
        $("#tablaDetalle").on("focus keyup", "tr", function(){
          var total = 0;

          var row = $(this).closest("tr");
          var cantidad = parseInt(row.find("input:eq(2)").val());
          var precio = parseFloat(row.find("input:eq(3)").val());
          var subtotal = cantidad * precio;
          row.find("input:eq(4)").val(isNaN(subtotal) ? "" : subtotal.toFixed(2));

            $(".subtotal").each(function () {
                var stval = parseFloat($(this).val());
                total += isNaN(stval) ? 0 : stval;
            });

            $('.delete-row').click(function(){
                var $fila = $(this).parents('tr');
                var valsub = parseFloat($fila.find('input:eq(4)').val());
                new Promise(function(done){
                    total -= isNaN(valsub) ? 0 : valsub;
                    $('.total').val(total.toFixed(2));
                    done();
                })
                .then(function(){
                   $fila.find('input:eq(4)').val(0);
                })
            });

            $('.total').val(total.toFixed(2));
        });
     </script>
    {% endblock %}
```

Si es que se percatan es para un pequeño sistema de ventas y necesito que se cargue el precio del producto. Si hay manera de poder hacer lo planteado? o por lo menos una pista para poder averiguar sobre como realizarlo?

Comment: Hola, me parece que la única forma sería usando AJAX. No veo otra forma de hacerlo desde Django.

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder @César he visto muchos comentarios de tu parte en otros post y son muy buenos pero vi algo sobre django_select2 se podra hacer con eso? si no ya normal lo hare con Ajax nada más

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solucionado!**
Lo hice de una forma muy sencilla:
Primero cree un api de productos con DRF(django rest framework) listando todos los productos que existen pero solo me interesaba el **id** del producto y su **precio** entonces cree un archivo **serializers.py** en mi app de ventas en el cual llamo al modelo de productos:

```
from rest_framework.serializers import ModelSerializer
from apps.producto.models import Producto

class ProductoSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Producto
        fields = ('id','precio')
```

Luego en mi vista llamo al serializer para la respectiva consulta:
Aquí importamos la ubicación del serializer e importamos la librería json
y el httpResponse si es que no lo tienen

```
import json
from django.http import HttpResponse
from apps.venta.serializers import ProductoSerializer
#Serializer de productos
class ProductoAPI(APIView):
    serializer = ProductoSerializer

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        lista = Producto.objects.all()
        response = self.serializer(lista, many=True)

        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response.data), content_type='application/json')
```

Y tan fácil como eso ahora sigue crearle una url para a través de ella poder acceder a esos datos(Url globales):

Importamos nuestra vista ya que estamos en las urls globales y la creamos:

```
from apps.venta.views import ProductoAPI
url(r'^api-producto',ProductoAPI.as_view(),name='api-producto',),
```

Y listo ya tenemos nuestra api configurada ahora simplemente a jugar con los datos.
Simplemente con **ajax** llame a esos datos en mi **template** de ventas de la siguiente manera:

```
var json = $.parseJSON($.ajax({
                url:  "{%  url 'api-producto' %}",
                dataType: "json", 
                async: false
            }).responseText);
```

Entonces cuando entre a ese template ya tendre accedo a esos datos que estan almacenados en la variable **json**
Ahora me di cuenta que cada select que te genera django te da un id único con el cual simplemente hice la comparación con el array en json que me trae el api con el select que esta en el template:

```
$('.precioxprod').change(function() {
                var idSelect = ($(this).val());
                precios = json.filter(function (idserver) { return idserver.id == idSelect; });
                $(this).closest("tr").find("input:eq(3)").val(precios[0].precio);
            });
```

**precioxprod** es la clase que le asigne al select para poder utilizarlo luego como selector.
 **idSelect** almacena cada id seleccionado en el select que te da django cuando es llave foranea.
**precios** aquí hace un filtro del arreglo json que me trae el api y se compara con su **id** con el **idSelect** para luego solo traerme un resultado que es es el precio **(precios[0].precio)** y listo solo nos queda decirle en donde muestre el resultado y eso es todo (:
Espero le sirva y le ayuda a alguien si es que quiere hacer algo similar.